# Go selection sort slower than bubble sort?

Tags: python, sorting, go, microbenchmark

I was doing some coding to practice algorithms, and I found something weird, when I implement the simple sorters in Python, with a random input of 99 elements, selection sort is faster than bubble sort:

[image: Python benchmark results]

This is my bubble and insert sort implementations in Python:

```py
from typing import List, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def bubble_sort(elems: List[T]) -> List[T]:
    """Sorts a list using the bubble sort algorithm"""
    if not elems:
        return elems

    for mx in range(len(elems), 0, -1):
        for idx in range(1, mx):
            if elems[idx - 1] > elems[idx]:
                elems[idx - 1], elems[idx] = elems[idx], elems[idx - 1]

    return elems


def selection_sort(elems: List[T]) -> List[T]:
    """Sorts a list using the selection sort algorithm"""
    if not elems:
        return elems
    n = len(elems)
    for i in range(0, n):
        smidx = i
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if elems[smidx] > elems[j]:
                smidx = j
        elems[i], elems[smidx] = elems[smidx], elems[i]
    return elems
```

And of course, the test (using PyTest and PyTest Benchmark):

```py
import random
from sorting import *

entry = [48, 41, 23, 97, 36, 12, 78, 47, 62, 74, 69, 42, 94, 82, 35, 5, 7, 68, 73, 83, 49, 11, 56, 70, 8, 2, 24, 52, 89, 37, 50, 93, 61, 88, 91, 60, 95, 32, 29, 9, 28, 79, 30, 99, 45, 27, 19, 55, 46, 72, 96, 81, 14, 86, 22, 1, 63, 3, 34, 31, 59, 58, 66, 65, 80, 84, 92, 20, 75, 25, 67, 64, 90, 33, 18, 44, 54, 40, 38, 16, 98, 77, 71, 51, 4, 21, 53, 43, 87, 57, 39, 6, 76, 13, 10, 15, 85, 17, 26]

expected = list(range(1, 100))

def test_bubble_sort(benchmark):
    x = entry.copy()
    assert benchmark(bubble_sort, x) == expected

def test_select_sort(benchmark):
    x = entry.copy()
    assert benchmark(selection_sort, x) == expected
```

Now, when I try and implement the same algorithms in Go, I get worse numbers for my select sort implementation:

```golang
package algo

func BubbleSort(elems []int) []int {
    if elems == nil {
        return nil
    }
    for mx := len(elems) - 1; mx >= 0; mx-- {
        for idx := 1; idx <= mx; idx++ {
            if elems[idx-1] > elems[idx] {
                elems[idx-1], elems[idx] = elems[idx], elems[idx-1]
            }
        }
    }
    return elems
}

func Selection(elems []int) []int {
    if elems == nil {
        return nil
    }
    n := len(elems) - 1
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
        maxIdx := i
        for j := i + 1; j <= n; j++ {
            if elems[j] < elems[maxIdx] {
                maxIdx = j
            }
        }
        elems[i], elems[maxIdx] = elems[maxIdx], elems[i]
    }
    return elems
}
```

[image: Go benchmark results]

Here is the test:

```golang
func BenchmarkBubbleSort(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        var longSeq = []int{48, 41, 23, 97, 36, 12, 78, 47, 62, 74, 69, 42, 94, 82, 35, 5, 7, 68, 73, 83, 49, 11, 56, 70, 8, 2, 24, 52, 89, 37, 50, 93, 61, 88, 91, 60, 95, 32, 29, 9, 28, 79, 30, 99, 45, 27, 19, 55, 46, 72, 96, 81, 14, 86, 22, 1, 63, 3, 34, 31, 59, 58, 66, 65, 80, 84, 92, 20, 75, 25, 67, 64, 90, 33, 18, 44, 54, 40, 38, 16, 98, 77, 71, 51, 4, 21, 53, 43, 87, 57, 39, 6, 76, 13, 10, 15, 85, 17, 26}
        BubbleSort(longSeq)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSelectionSort(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        var longSeq = []int{48, 41, 23, 97, 36, 12, 78, 47, 62, 74, 69, 42, 94, 82, 35, 5, 7, 68, 73, 83, 49, 11, 56, 70, 8, 2, 24, 52, 89, 37, 50, 93, 61, 88, 91, 60, 95, 32, 29, 9, 28, 79, 30, 99, 45, 27, 19, 55, 46, 72, 96, 81, 14, 86, 22, 1, 63, 3, 34, 31, 59, 58, 66, 65, 80, 84, 92, 20, 75, 25, 67, 64, 90, 33, 18, 44, 54, 40, 38, 16, 98, 77, 71, 51, 4, 21, 53, 43, 87, 57, 39, 6, 76, 13, 10, 15, 85, 17, 26}
        Selection(longSeq)
    }
}
```

Yes, I know select sort can be worse than bubble sort for the best case scenario (I don't think it is this the case based in a shuffled input), but why, if that is the case, why in Python it behaves like expected? (faster than bubble sort).

I tried already changing the for loops to range in Go but the timing is similar. Maybe somebody has an idea what is happening here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: take care that because you use one singleton variable the array is sorted once across all tests...

Comment: So you do your benchmark based on a single predefined array even though different sort algorithms have different runtimes based on the specific input? You should at least use lots of different inputs to actually compare your implementation unless your implementations will only ever used with the one specific input you've used for benchmarking. Also, BubbleSort is very fast if the array is already sorted which it is after a single run - i.e. all other iterations in the benchmark operate on the already sorted array.

Comment: Thanks @mh-cbon I think your answer gave me a lot of insight (I really thought Go test created a separate process for each benchmark in the same way PyTest does, your comment was super helpful!

Comment: @mh-cbon I changed the tests, numbers are similar, bubble sort is still faster than selection sort in my tests with Go (not with Python, there it is still faster).

Comment: @cpieto yes i figure that out. I believe  something is going on here. But unless you provide more data to prove your findings, hard to make people interested. Both algorithms are bound to the total number of iterations, so one should be twice bigger than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarking a sort algorithm with a fixed set of numbers makes no sense in the first place since the number of steps involved to sort not only depends on the algorithm but also on the specific input. One algorithm might be faster with one input, the other with a different input.

Ignoring this your Python code does not even measure the performance of sorting a specific array. Instead it takes a single global array, copies it (`entry.copy()`) before doing the benchmark (i.e. before running the sort function many times), sorts it exactly once in-place and from then one every "sorting" is done on the already sorted array. Thus your Python code measures one sorting of the original input and many sorting of the already sorted input.

Contrary to this the Go implementation starts with a fresh array for each run of the sort function. Thus your Go code measures many sorting of the original input.

In other words: you are measuring totally different things in Python and Go.

Comment: I suspected that as well so I changed the test in Python to `assert benchmark(selection_sort, entry.copy()) == expected` to start with a fresh copy of the array all the time. The numbers are still very similar

Comment: @cprieto: benchmark is running many `selection_sort` with the **result** of a single `entry.copy()` and will not call `entry.copy()` for each call of `selection_sort`. You have to do the copy in the sort routine itself to make sure that you don't change the input value.